# "As is not unusual with him": correct? Is the verb mandatory?

Tags: syntax

If we are describing a book written by John Doe, it seems like

"As **is** not unusual with John Doe, sentences are short."

is used far more than

"As not unusual with John Doe, sentences are short."

I therefore suspect that the second phrase is either incorrect or at least less elegant.

Can anyone please confirm?

And confirm that there is nothing wrong with the first phrase?

Comment: The syntactic issue you're asking about would be exactly the same without the irrelevant negation. That's it say, you could compare ***as is common with XXX*** to the "verbless" version ***as common with XXX***. The difference between them is that the second version (which is much less common) only works in contexts like *Recurrent headache appears to be as common with children as with adults*. But the question as presented here lacks the necessary context that would allow us to decide which version is correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I mentioned the negation, because it seemed to me that it may have made the phrase(s) especially unusual / non-idiomatic. It does not appear to be the case. Also, it seems to me that the negation is not negligible here, in that, unless I am mistaken, it could not be used in your "recurrent headache" example. Since I intend to use this phrase at the beginning of a sentence (which I should have mentioned), I will stick to "as is not unusual with XXX."

Comment: I wasn't trying to imply that "common" is somehow better than "not unusual". Just that the negation itself doesn't affect the matter of whether or not the verb ***is*** should be included or not. Note that unless you modify your question to include an example context (and if appropriate, *tell us exactly what you want your example to **mean***), your question will probably be closed without anyone posting formal "Answers" that you can accept or upvote. I have already cast my closevote for that reason, and if/when 4 others do the same, the question will be closed.

Comment: "Common" better than "not unusual": I don't believe I implied that either. What I did imply (though I would be glad to be proven wrong) is that the negation seems to actually affect the matter, in that I fail to see how one could use "as NOT unusual / usual / uncommon / common" in your "recurrent headache" example. It seems to me that the negation leaves only one meaning available, that is, roughly: "what I am going to tell next does not come as a total surprise, because it is not unusual for XXX to act this way." But I will gladly edit my question if you think it is necessary.

Comment: But I agree that my question was not crystal-clear, and that it could have been that I wanted to (wrongly, I believe) write "Recurrent headache appears to be as not unusual with children as with adults." I will therefore edit my question, though you actually answered it, for which I am grateful.

Comment: To rephrase: I wasn't trying to imply that "common" and "not unusual" are particularly ***synonymous***. There's no doubt that in your "not a total surprise" example, there would be a considerable difference in emphasis between "common" and "not unusual". My point was simply that using the negated version or not makes no difference to the syntactic aspect being queried here (whether or not to include the word ***is***). To repeat my *second* point - you still haven't edited to include an actual *sentence* (together with *intended meaning*) within which you want to include the cited text.

Comment: Dear FumbleFingers, 1/ "Synonymous": I don't think I brought up such an issue either 2/ "using the negated version or not makes no difference to the syntactic aspect being queried here (whether or not to include the word "is")": given your first comment, I still fail to see how the negated version could be used without "is," hence a syntactic impact in my opinion, but I guess I see what you mean 3/ I am not sure why a sentence is required on top of the context I gave, but again, you often give thorough answers, for which I am grateful; I will therefore trust you and re-edit my question.

Comment: You ***need*** to include the verb ***is*** in your example sentence *As is not unusual with John Doe, sentences are short*. By the same token, the verb is also required in *As **is common** with John Doe, sentences are short*. BUT - now there's more complete context for me to get my teeth into, I will just point out that *this is only my opinion*, amnd others may be somewhat more relaxed. I say this because so far as I'm concerned, that same verb is actually *optional* in non-negated *As [is] **usual / expected** with John, he got drunk*.

Comment: I didn't realise until now that your negation was throwing me off the scent. Did you in fact *deliberately* introduce negation because you already knew that ***as usual*** is an established collocation that rarely includes ***is***?

Comment: Thanks for these very clear comments. I knew of "as usual" as in "business as usual," but was not even sure it was correct when used at the beginning of a sentence. I introduced negation simply because I intend to use it this way, and I did not remove it because I thought it may have an impact, maybe not on syntax, but on how commonly it was used. I later realized that it has at least the syntactical impact that negation cannot be used without "is," in any circumstance, neither with my intended meaning, nor with your "recurrent headache" meaning (of which I had not initially thought).

Comment: If you and I had had similar lengthy comment exchanges in the past, that normally ended successfully for you in your quest for "Anglophonic Enlightenment" I'd be able to write ***As usual**, we got there in the end!* But if those hypothetical earlier comment exchanges ***hadn't*** usually helped you understand something better (where I'm assuming this current one ***has***), it certainly wouldn't be remotely idiomatic to write ***As [is] not usual**, we got there in the end!* For that situation, you'd start with something like ***Unexpectedly,*** or ***Amazingly,** [we got there this time!]*